# How to assign file data downloaded by JavaScript function to the file that is saved

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a VueJS 1 site, I create download links for files like this:

```
<a download={{d.fileName}} 
  href="#null" 
  v-on:click="getFile(d.guid);" 
  target="_blank">
  {{d.fileName}}</a>
```

The download function is as below, and I can see from the network that the file data is received from the server when I click on the link.
The file object contains the file data, but I don't see how I can assign the content of the file object to what is downloaded in the browser. 
When you click on the link, a file is downloaded with the correct name, but it contains HTML from my site instead of the file data.

```
download: function() {
  var that = this;
  AXIOS('GET', '/file/'  + guid).then(function (response) {
    that.file = response.data;
  });
  return that.file;
}
```

How can I get the file data to be downloaded?

Comment: The file url should be in the `href` attribute. Now the `href` points to the page it is already on (`http://yoursite.com/yourpage#null`) so it will download the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The file URL should be in in the link's `href` attribute.

Now the href points to the page it is already on (`http://yoursite.com/yourpage#null`) so it will download the HTML from the current page instead of the file.

The resulting HTML of the link should look like this:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/file/yourfile.ext" 
   download="yourfile.ext" 
   target="_blank">yourfile.ext</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What you say is true in itself, but in this case the file isn't a real file - the data for the file comes from the server's response, and  if I make the response URL to be something like http://yoursite.com/file/yourfile.ext and point the href to that, then the request goes without the Authorization header.  Adding the Authorization header must be done in Javascript, which is why I need to use that AXIOS function somewhere!